# How to access database of JasperReports Server via API?

Tags: api, jasper-reports, jasperserver

Can we access Database of *JasperReports Server* server through its API?

And do that allow us to make run time report?

If so how can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can access JasperServer's resources using it's SOAP API... java-client can be found in jasperserver-common-ws-[VERSION].jar...
 examples of usage are in doc folder of jasperserver as well... Document you need is "Jasper Server Web Services Guide"

Regards..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a page which has a full example of how to write a c program to call an existing Jasper report from a remote client.
http://community.ingres.com/wiki/Jaspersoft_WebServices_C_API

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following [wiki](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/DataSources).

It shows you how to set up a Microsoft Sql Server as a JDBC DataSource on a Jasper Server.